# join two patrition dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have two dataframes with partition level 2. Dataframes are small probably around 100 rows each.

df1 :

```
col1    columnindex
null        1
null        2
null        3
null        4
100         5
101         6
102         7
103         8
104         9
105         10
```

df2:

```
col2    columnindex
100         1
200         2
null        3
null        4
100         5
101         6
null        7
103         8
null        9
105         10
```

my final df will be join of df1 and df2 based on columnindex.

```
col1    col2    columnindex
null    100       1
null    200       2
null    null      3
null    null      4
100     100       5
101     101       6
102     null      7
103     103       8
104     null      9
105     105       10
```

But when I am joining two data frames as per below it looks it is shuffling and giving me the incorrect results. Is there any way I can do which avoid shuffling.

```
df1.join(df2, df1.columnindex == df2.columnindex, 'inner')
```

Comment: Thanks for your question. Can you provide some "fake" data via copy paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this depends on what do you mean by shuffling.

```
join1 = spark.createDataFrame([(None, 1), (None, 2), (None, 3), (100, 5), (101, 6), (105, 10)], ['col1', 'columnindex'])
join2 = spark.createDataFrame([(100, 1), (200, 2), (None, 3), (100, 5), (101, 6), (None, 10)], ['col2', 'columnindex'])
joined = join1.join(join2, ['columnindex'], 'inner').select(['columnindex', 'col1', 'col2'])
joined.show()
```

results in:

```
+-----------+----+----+
|columnindex|col1|col2|
+-----------+----+----+
|          2|null| 200|
|          5| 100| 100|
|          3|null|null|
|          6| 101| 101|
|          1|null| 100|
|         10| 105|null|
+-----------+----+----+
```

Which is a correct result - each columnindex corresponds to proper values from both dataframes and if you do any further computations, this shouldn't be a problem.
However, if you want values to be ordered by columnindex, you can do it with `orderBy`

```
joined.orderBy('columnindex').show()
```

```
+-----------+----+----+
|columnindex|col1|col2|
+-----------+----+----+
|          1|null| 100|
|          2|null| 200|
|          3|null|null|
|          5| 100| 100|
|          6| 101| 101|
|         10| 105|null|
+-----------+----+----+
```

A quick note on join - if you use `df1.columnindex == df2.columnindex`, this is going to result in duplicated columnindex column, which you will have to solve before sorting it with `orderBy`, that's why it's easier to pass column name as a list argument to `join` as above.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, this is my answer, Vikrant has contributed formatting fixes  if you found the answer useful please upvote and mark it as accepted

Comment: @ Rajesh Meher.. Yes, I have just contributed towards formatting, You can accept this answer as a owner. Thanks